# How to specify leading field names with mongoimport?

Tags: database, mongodb, csv, import

I'm importing a very large csv file to mongodb which follows the following format:

```
"zzzàms@hotmail.com","12071988"
"zzzг ms@hotmail.com","12071988"
"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@bk.ru","MA15042002"
"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@list.ru","MA15042002"
"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@rambler.ru","MA15042002"
"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@yandex.ru","MA15042002"
```

However, I am not certain how many fields / columns will follow, after the email field.

I have imported using this command:

```
mongoimport -d emails -c second --file all.csv --type csv --fields email, number
```

However, any fields / columns after number field is issued a default value of 'field2', 'field3' and so on.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5cd95e598f1e910d353e3b"), "email" : "00-amber-00@embarqmail.com", " number" : "number1", "field2" : "number2" }
```

How can I put anything after the number field in the same column, so it's classified as 'number'?

Sometimes, one entry has maybe 40 columns.

I don't wish to modify the csv file unless it is really necessary.

Sorry, english is not first language, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Unix` commands like `awk` to parse the line to `json` as per the logic and `stdin` to `mongoimport`

sample file

```
saravana@ubuntu:~$ cat sample-doc.txt 
"zzzàms@hotmail.com","12071988"
"zzzг ms@hotmail.com","12071988"
"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@bk.ru","MA15042002"
"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@list.ru","MA15042002"
"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@rambler.ru","MA15042002","34534"
"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@yandex.ru","MA15042002","1232434","3435435","53534"
```

`awk` to convert `json`, email followed by numbers

```
saravana@ubuntu:~$ cat sample-doc.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print "{ email :" $1 ", numbers : [ " substr($0,length($1)+2) " ] } " }'
{ email :"zzzàms@hotmail.com", numbers : [ "12071988" ] } 
{ email :"zzzг ms@hotmail.com", numbers : [ "12071988" ] } 
{ email :"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@bk.ru", numbers : [ "MA15042002" ] } 
{ email :"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@list.ru", numbers : [ "MA15042002" ] } 
{ email :"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@rambler.ru", numbers : [ "MA15042002","34534" ] } 
{ email :"zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@yandex.ru", numbers : [ "MA15042002","1232434","3435435","53534" ] } 
saravana@ubuntu:~$
```

`mongoimport` using `stdin`

```
saravana@ubuntu:~$ cat sample-doc.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print "{ email :" $1 ", numbers : [ " substr($0,length($1)+2) " ] } " }' | mongoimport --type json --db test --collection emailnos -v
2018-01-17T09:58:11.559+0530    reading from stdin
2018-01-17T09:58:11.559+0530    using fields: 
2018-01-17T09:58:11.561+0530    connected to: localhost
2018-01-17T09:58:11.561+0530    ns: test.emailnos
2018-01-17T09:58:11.561+0530    connected to node type: standalone
2018-01-17T09:58:11.561+0530    using write concern: w='1', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
2018-01-17T09:58:11.561+0530    using write concern: w='1', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
2018-01-17T09:58:11.726+0530    imported 6 documents
```

collection

```
> db.emailnos.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5ed0dbead4f5f7ae68da90"), "email" : "zzzàms@hotmail.com", "numbers" : [ "12071988" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5ed0dbead4f5f7ae68da91"), "email" : "zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@list.ru", "numbers" : [ "MA15042002" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5ed0dbead4f5f7ae68da92"), "email" : "zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@rambler.ru", "numbers" : [ "MA15042002", "34534" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5ed0dbead4f5f7ae68da93"), "email" : "zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@yandex.ru", "numbers" : [ "MA15042002", "1232434", "3435435", "53534" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5ed0dbead4f5f7ae68da94"), "email" : "zzzг ms@hotmail.com", "numbers" : [ "12071988" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5ed0dbead4f5f7ae68da95"), "email" : "zzпїѕпїѕmmbbii2@bk.ru", "numbers" : [ "MA15042002" ] }
>
```